# How to detect that a control is being moved?

Tags: wpf, position, drag, detect

Suppose I have a window with a custom UserControl, and the UserControl has a textbox inside.  When I drag the window around, how can the TextBox detect that it is being moved ?

I tried to search around its RenderTransform property, there is that Change event that gets fired when "the Freezable object or one of its objects change". Nothing conclusive..

Edit :

In my case, I don't see the window, all I see is the UserControl and I can't go any higher.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to subscribe to the Window events, as your textbox is not actually moving (its most likely in the same position relevant to the window) so you can subscribe to the `Window.LocationChanged` event to be notified when the window is moved.

But Also If your control does not have an absolute position then you will need to parse `Window.SizeChanged` which will tell you when the user has resized the window, but it’s a discrete final event as opposed to an in-progress event.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't work in my case because actually the textbox is inside a UserControl, which is inside a sticky mdi window. From my code I can't see the mdi so I can't do anything based on it. I said that I had a Window just to simplify the case. What I need to do is to approach this case differently.  It shouldn't be a frame that fires an event and tell everyone that they have been moved around. The textbox has to detect that its location has changed, by itself.

Comment: This also won't work for applications that use drag and drop controls... which is the problem I have.

Answer (score 7):

Try subscribing to the LayoutUpdated event of the UserControl.

Comment: This is a good tip. When using LayoutUpdated, make sure to check to see if the control has moved before doing expensive work. The LayoutUpdated event fires for more than position changes. If you animate anything over the control, the LayoutUpdated event tends to fire a LOT.

Comment: This is very nice solution when your control is in a windowsformhost and window is not accessible (to my knowledge)